# Oracle - select statement to rollup multiple tables within a time frame

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I have 3 Oracle tables for a project that link a demo Transaction table to Transaction_Customer and Transaction_Employee as shown below. Each transaction can have multiple customers involved and many employees involved.

I am trying to write a SQL query which will list each Customer_ID that has had transactions with multiple employees within a one period. I would like the output to include a single row for each Customer_ID with a comma separated list of which Employee_IDs had a transaction with that customer.

The output should look like this:

```
Customer_ID|Employees
601|007,008,009
```

The basic query to join the tables together looks like this:

```
select * from transactions t
left join transactions_customer tc
on t.t_id = tc.t_id
left join transactions_employee te
on t.t_id = te.t_id
```

How do I get this do I finish this assignment and get the query working the way intended?

Thank you!

Transactions

```
T_ID|Date|Amount
1|1/10/2017|100
2|1/10/2017|200
3|1/31/2017|150
4|2/16/2017|175
5|2/17/2017|175
6|2/18/2017|185
```

Transactions_Customer

```
T_ID|Customer_ID
1|600
1|601
1|602
2|605
3|606
4|601
5|607
6|607
```

Transactions_Employee

```
T_ID|Employee_ID
1|007
1|008
2|009
3|008
4|009
5|007
6|007
```

Comment: And what do you want the output to be?  Please edit the question with desired results.

Comment: Why would a customer appear multiple times on a single transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select tc.Customer_id,
       listagg(te.employee_id, ',') within group (order by te.employee_id) as employees
from Transactions_Customer tc join
     Transactions_Employee te
     on tc.t_id = te.t_id
group by tc.Customer_id;
```

You only need the `Transactions` table for filtering on the date.  Your question alludes to such filtering but does not exactly describe it, so I left it out.

Edit:

The customer data (and perhaps the employees data too) has duplicates.  To avoid these in the output:

```
select tc.Customer_id,
       listagg(te.employee_id, ',') within group (order by te.employee_id) as employees
from (select distinct tc.t_id, tc.customer_id
      from Transactions_Customer tc
     ) tc join
     (select distinct te.t_id, te.employee_id
      from Transactions_Employee te
     ) te
     on tc.t_id = te.t_id
group by tc.Customer_id;
```

Comment: Sorry! That was by mistake! I dont think this is factoring in the 1 week time period?

Comment: @AAA . . . As I explain in the answer, you need to join in the `transactions` table, but your question doesn't specify an actual time period.

Comment: One week of the transaction... I.E. transaction 4,5,6 are within 1 week